# Rotate TextView in Canvas, Android

Tags: android, textview

I'm trying to rotate a `TextView` but I have several problems with the different resolutions.  I override `onDraw` method in this way

```
canvas.save();
canvas.rotate(-90,60,60);
super.onDraw(canvas);
canvas.restore();
```

But I cannot have the same result in different devices. I think because of `pivotX` and `pivotY` measure index parameters in the rotate method. In 320x480 it runs fine, in 240x320 `TextView` is clipped.

Has anyone had the same problem?

Answer (score 0):

I think you have to first dynamically get window heigth and width of window and according it you have to set it.